# Python Loop to printout data and write CSV yields "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried endlessly to solve this problem and I still cant figure it out. The perplexing part of my code is as follows -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import lxml
import csv

with open('C:\Python\Test\xyz.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    variables = {}
    for row in reader:
        variables[row[0]] = row[1:]

for i in variables:
    super = (variables.get(i)[0])
    duper = (variables.get(i)[1])
    ticker = i

    outfile = open("finale.csv", "a", newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Python/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://example.com/" + super + super)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    driver.quit()

    titles = soup.select("table#example")[0]
    list_row =[[tab_d.text for tab_d in item.select('td')]
                    for item in titles.select('tr')]

for data in list_row:
    printout = ([ticker,data])
    writer.writerow(printout)

outfile.close()

EDIT
The traceback is as follows 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Windy/Windy.py", line 31, in <module>
    titles = soup.select("table#example")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

which points to line    titles = soup.select("table#example")[0]

Whenever I run this, I get the error "IndexError: list index out of range". It produces the CSV as desired, but every time I run it the length of the CSV output changes, so its breaking at random points. Im assuming it has something to do with the number of variables in the dictionary and running through them ?

Also, I have made sure that my CSV has no blank rows, and have even used a TXT file to be positive, which gave the same result.

Thanks as always for all your help !

Comment: (a) At what line does this error happen? (b) Could you provide a sample from `xyz.txt`? (c) Is it possible that you have a row with a single value only?

Comment: ALWAYS include the full traceback - it's telling you exactly where the error occurred, which we can only guess at based on what you've posted so far.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the traceback and Edited above. Appreciate the help -

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places where your code could go wrong, so please look for the line of code in the error message. Basically any of places where you index a variable could produce that error.

For any place where you retrieve a value from an index position, try to wrap that statement in a

```
if x:
  statement
```

and debug lengths and values. Try to work on your troubleshooting techniques to become a more efficient coder and problem solver :)

Also, when working with files, always use a context manager to avoid any potential troubles.
In your case:

```
with open('filename.file', 'a') as f:
  f.write(value)
```

Comment: if x is a very smart trouble shooting technique, I should have thought of that, ty. Working on it now